# Can a loop lock itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can a loop lock itself?

Last night the test team opened a strange ticked.
The app have a grid where the user can check incidents to be postponed
the tester selected two incidents (ids: 1 and 5), postponed both but one don't got the status updated

I know the [Incident] table must be updated and one new record inserted at the [IncidentDetail] table
I queried both and fond this:

```
Id IncidentKindCode TransportEntryId CreateDate             IncidentStatus CloseDate
-- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------------- -------------- ---------
1  11301            52               2014-08-26 19:23:21.47 1              NULL
5  11301            56               2014-08-26 20:06:17.94 0              NULL

Id IncidentId  InsertDate             DetailKind Reason    IncidentUser PostponeDate
-- ----------- ---------------------- ---------- --------- ------------ -----------------------
9  1           2014-08-26 20:28:37.37 1          TEST TEST 8            2014-08-27 00:00:00.000
10 5           2014-08-26 20:28:37.37 1          TEST TEST 8            2014-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

The tester complain is valid since both [Incident].[IncidentStatus] values must be zero at this point.
After digging in it I captured the exact query the app sent to the server (thanks to the profiler).

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@IDINCIDENT varchar(max) ,@REASON varchar(max) ,@USERCODE varchar(max) ,@POSTPONEDATE varchar(max) ',N'
DECLARE @ARRAY VARCHAR(8000), @DELIMITADOR VARCHAR(100), @SELECTEDID VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @ARRAY = @IDINCIDENT
SELECT @DELIMITADOR = '';''

IF LEN(@ARRAY) > 0 SET @ARRAY = @ARRAY + @DELIMITADOR

WHILE LEN(@ARRAY) > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @SELECTEDID = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ARRAY, 1,
    CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) - 1))

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].Incident SET INCIDENTSTATUS = 1 WHERE ID = @SELECTEDID
        INSERT [dbo].IncidentDetail (INCIDENTID, DETAILKIND, REASON, INCIDENTUSER, POSTPONEDATE)
                       VALUES (@SELECTEDID, 1, @REASON, @USERCODE, @POSTPONEDATE);
    END

    SELECT @ARRAY = SUBSTRING(@ARRAY,
    CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) + 1, LEN(@ARRAY))
END
',@IDINCIDENT='1;5',@REASON='querty',@USERCODE='1',@POSTPONEDATE='2014-08-28 00:00:00'
select @p1
```

No triggers, no other update no pending transactions.
As far I know, even if the first loop iteration blocked the second one to the the point the update fails, a exception must be raised and all the transaction be rolled back.

Seems ilogical the update can fail while the insert works.
All columns got standart types (Int, Varchar(100), DateTime, etc) also I tested for implicit casts issues.

This issue happened only once and cannot be reproduced, even using a backup but I'm afraid it can happen again at production if I cannot find why it happened.

Comment: Errors in SQL Server sometimes abort the batch, sometimes they don't. Same for the transaction and connection. (Yes, this is nasty.); So your update might fail and the insert might go through. Maybe your app is throwing away errors.

Comment: And no, a transaction cannot block or deadlock on itself.

Comment: Intra-query deadlocks can and do happen. I've encountered them myself in production code:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2008/09/24/today-s-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks.aspx

Comment: logs are truncated before I gained access to it. If it throwed something at that time we ill never know. I just need some clue to start with and maybe try to automate a test to try reproduce it (hate erratic error)

Comment: While the SQL you profiled may be the same as the issue you encountered, I wouldn't assume that the parameter for @IDINCIDENT is the same.  I think it's likely that it was '1' and not '1;5'.  This seems more likely than a deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not understood what you actually want to do. I am giving you a way based on what i understood. You can check whether that entry gets updated or not, if updated then you insert in IncidentDetail.

```
UPDATE [dbo].Incident SET INCIDENTSTATUS = 1 WHERE ID = @SELECTEDID

If Exists(  Select  1
            From    [dbo].Incident As I
            Where   I.ID = @SELECTEDID
                    And I.INCIDENTSTATUS = 1
         )
Begin
    INSERT [dbo].IncidentDetail (INCIDENTID, DETAILKIND, REASON, INCIDENTUSER, POSTPONEDATE)
                       VALUES (@SELECTEDID, 1, @REASON, @USERCODE, @POSTPONEDATE);
End
```

Comment: After a couple of days we found the issue was caused by another coworker deleted a row and we blind believed that was not the problem at first. Also I found a lot of references saying that a loop cannot lock itself (the question was silly from start and i ill close it). I ill not delete it to serve as a reference since many people visited it. Also ill upvote your answer because it can be usefull for someone